# How to add time to Liferay portlet

Tags: java, liferay

I am very new at Liferay Portal, I just created my first portlet which has a table and a submit button, when I click on the button it take me to the "*processAction*" function where I call a function from my own class which reads an Excel file and write it into a List and then this List is passed to the view.jsp and shown in the table. Now I need to add time to it, by which I mean I want to add 2 row of the Excel file into the table every 5 secend, in other words, I do not want to show all the table at once. Please below find my "*processAction*" :

```
public void processAction(
        ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {
    ReadExcelDemo readExcelDemo = new ReadExcelDemo();
    actionRequest.setAttribute("allElementsFromExcelFile",readExcelDemo.readExcel());
}
```

Comment: Do you want to append rows to existed table using AJAX ?

Comment: AJAX option would be most suitable in this case.

Comment: I have no knowledge about AJAX so is that a very time-consuming to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this code in your view.jsp page between headers:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">
```